# Sitemap and XML sitemap

Tags: xml-sitemap

I originally had a sitemap using the sitemap module. I've now installed and enable dthe xml sitemap module instead. After following the instructions and configuring xml sitemap, when I go to mysite/sitemap.xml all I see is an unstyled page with an ugly table listing the Links.

How would I go about styling this sitemap? I was expecting it to work like the Sitemap module does and generate a page using a default template, but I guess I was wrong, or am I?

How should a sitemap.xml display after it's been set up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sitemap.xml is used to provide a way for search engines to index your site. It should not be used by your website users.

Comment: Thank you @Serpiente

Is it common to be using both the sitemap and xml sitemap modules at the same time?

Comment: I can only talk for myself - I am doing that yes.